# apache2 suddenly failing to serve https

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, apache2

apache2 v.2.41 on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (WSL2) is suddenly not connecting over https, in browser or via `wget`.

It's been working for months, and I haven't changed anything.

I tried restarting Apache; it's still not working.

My sites's `.conf` file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin <redacted>
    ServerName penguin.linux.test
    ServerAlias www.penguin.linux.test
    DocumentRoot /home/<redacted>/www
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I followed [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-20-04) to create a self-signed cert, several months ago. I just ran this again:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
```

No errors in `error.log`. But `access.log` shows *some* access when I use the browser:

```
::1 - - [30/Jan/2023:08:34:02 -0600] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [30/Jan/2023:08:34:05 -0600] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [30/Jan/2023:08:34:06 -0600] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f (internal dummy connection)"
172.27.224.1 - - [30/Jan/2023:08:36:24 -0600] "GET /src/ HTTP/1.1" 200 29952 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

`telnet [local IP] 443` is able to connect, which is weird.

The browser doesn't seem to ever timeout. Chrome Dev Tools shows no network requests.

Comment: `telnet [local IP] 443` shows that you can establish a TCP connection (in other words there is something listening on port 443)  - it does not validate if that something properly supports either TLS/SSL and/or HTTPS.  - use for instance `openssl s_client -connect [IP]:443` and/or `curl -kv https://local-ip/`  to verify that

Comment: Thanks. For whatever reason, it started working again. Weird.